# java tools for extracting relevant keywords/tags from articles

Tags: java, metadata, search-engine, data-mining

I'm looking for java based tools for extracting relevant tags from a given article.
I need a tool that will basically try and identify what are the main subjects and terms a given article is related to.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to parse the article's HTML and query for the parts of the document you are interested in searching.  Then you can apply a simple algorithm of your own design to determine tags/keywords.

Like for instance, `split()` the text on whitespace and then count how many times each word occurs.  The words that occur the most (ignoring things like "and", "the", "if", etc.) are good candidates for keywords.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm interested in the tokenization part. I'm aware of stemming and how it works. But I'm looking for an algorithm that already does it for a general case.

Answer (score 5):

Check the following key words/topics extraction software/tools:

- [Kea](http://www.nzdl.org/Kea/download.html) - key word extraction
- [Tmt](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.3/) - Stanford topic detection toolkit (integration with Excel, scripts written in Scala), it supports a semi-automatic topic detection mode (with user's feedback).
- [maui](http://code.google.com/p/maui-indexer/)

If you would like to develop your own topic detection system, you should take a look on [LDA implementation in mallet](http://wbarczynski.org/wp/2011/11/05/lda-with-mallet/) (link to a working LDA sample, the one on mallet homepage does not work with the newest [mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) version).